# make animated select work with a recent jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a nice animated select drop box located in

### [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/).

That site also gives you the source code. I want to place that control in my html page. The problem is that I am already using a jquery library (jquery-1.6.min.js) and the control that I want to download uses an older jquery library (1.4.3)  if I include both libraries on my project the html page will not load. also if I use the older library my page does not work eather. it will be nice if I could integrate that control in my html page.

One solution that I have worked out:

I downloaded the sorce code and place it in a directory. I edit the html page so that I am just left of with the drop down (got rid of the footer, title, etc). Then I used the iFram element to place the content of that html page inside a div. the problem with that is that it is hard to send commands to the functions. in other words I will like to fire an event in my working html page when something happens inside the page hosted by the iframe element.

Comment: What happens if you only include the current version?

Comment: the drop down does not work... And if I use that library instead of the one I am using my site does not work...

Comment: I am thinking about creating that drop down from scratch. the site gives you the images and it will not be to complicated to replicate I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change the "className" to "class"... oddly it worked in older versions of jQuery, but not 1.6+. Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/G7jSC/).

```
var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>',{
    width : select.outerWidth(),
    class : 'tzSelect', // this was className
    html  : '<div class="selectBox"></div>'
});

var dropDown = $('<ul>',{class :'dropDown'}); // this was className
```